# static class variable scope issue in C# winforms - why doesn't this bit of code work?

Tags: c#, winforms, static, static-variables

I've got two different forms in my WinForms app (MainForm and Form2 say).  They both ask for an access of MyDataSet, via a "getInstance" static method.  The issue is after MainForm has got an instance, when Form2 needs to get an instance the static "myDataSet" variable is null, whereas I expect to have been already set?  Any ideas?

```
public class MyDataSet
{
    public static MyDataSet myDataSet;   
       // This was null 2nd call to getInstance

    private DataSet myData = new DataSet();

    public static MyDataSet GetInstance()
    {
        if (myDataSet == null)
        {
            return new MyDataSet();
        }
        else
        {
            return myDataSet;
        }
    }
```

So it almost seems the static "myDataSet" variable isn't working in terms of only having once instance?

Comment: As an aside, the myDataSet static member really should be private.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you forgot to assign the newly create instance to myDataset

```
if(myDataSet == null)
{
    myDataSet = new MyDataSet();
}
return myDataSet
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set `myDataSet`

This is the correct code:

```
public class MyDataSet
{
    public static MyDataSet myDataSet;   
       // This was null 2nd call to getInstance

    private DataSet myData = new DataSet();

    public static MyDataSet GetInstance()
    {
        if (myDataSet == null)
        {
            myDataSet =new MyDataSet();
        }

            return myDataSet;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyDataSet
{
    public static MyDataSet myDataSet;   
       // This was null 2nd call to getInstance

    private DataSet myData = new DataSet();

    public static MyDataSet GetInstance()
    {
        if (myDataSet == null)
        {
            myDataSet = new MyDataSet();      // Changed at this point
            return myDataSet;
        }
        else
        {
            return myDataSet;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) from Jon Skeet. As others have said you are not setting the variable but you might also want to implement a more robust pattern, or perhaps get rid of the singleton. As it is you could end up multiple instances being created of MyDataSet.

I would go with the fourth or fifth version, if you need a singleton.